# build user email list in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have a contact form at the footer of every page in the website. User's will be using it to send email to the admin. I've been able to code it up till this part. Now I want to insert the user email addresses into the database. i.e user will use the contact form and the email will be send to admin plus his/her email address will be stored in the database for future uses. Also I need to show this list in the wordpress admin panel.

Thanks in advance for help.

```
//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$message = $_POST['user_msg'];

// sending email from wordpress core mail function.
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);


<form id="footerForm" action="#" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" id="" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['user_name']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['user_email']); ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <textarea id="" name="user_msg" class="form-control" style="height: 155px;" placeholder="Message"><?php echo esc_attr($_POST['user_msg']); ?></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="padding-top: 9px;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/submit-btn.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Post some code and your DB model

Comment: sure. just give me a sec

Comment: Why you have written the code for contact form when plugin is there ?

You can use Contact form 7 and contact form DB plugins for this purpose.
This will make your work easier

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I want to do this in custom coding. Thanks.